# Cannot use a different directory for lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, windows

I'm having a bit of a problem. I'm trying to include source code in an appendix in latex. I use the following line in order to add the source code:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=C]{"C:\work\EA10080\trunk\Programming\Secondary_side\full_function\Submodules\ePWM.c"}
```

but I get the following error:

> 398 Undefined control sequence.  \lst@inputpath "C:\work 
>                                      \EA 10080\trunk \Programming \Secondary _... l.398 ...ry_side\full_function\Submodules\ePWM.c"}

What am I doing wrong? I'm using the package listing, color and the document class is report.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{numbers=left,commentstyle=\color{mygreen},keywordstyle=\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Source Code for PWM}
\label{sec:A}

\lstinputlisting[language=C]{"C:\work\EA10080\trunk\Programming\Secondary_side\full_function\Submodules\ePWM.c"}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Also, maybe I should mention that adding the source code "manually" (using \begin{listing} and then writing the code) works fine. It's much less practical though.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The problem is probably having a lot of `\ ` characters in your path and `_` characters as well.

Comment: I just tried that but got the following error:

"
398
LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.398 ...side\\full_function\\Submodules\\ePWM.c"}
"

Comment: Unusual idea: Replace all `\\ ` characters in your path by `/`, but keep `\_`. such as `\lstinputlisting[language=C]{"C:/Work/EA10080/ etc}`

Comment: Yeah. I just had that idea too. I tried it and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Changing `\` to `/` should work!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{numbers=left,commentstyle=\color{mygreen},keywordstyle=\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Source Code for PWM}
\label{sec:A}

\lstinputlisting[language=C]{"C:/work/EA10080/trunk/Programming/Secondary_side/full_function/Submodules/ePWM.c"}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `_` characters occuring in the pathname are probably still a source of complaints

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I don't think so. :-)

Comment: Are `_` characters in pathnames converted by `listings` such as not being interpreted as starting an subscript? Is the activeness of `_` changed?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I have tried my code above and there is no problem with `_` (underscore). The internal details are beyond my understanding. :-)

Comment: Well, anyway, if it works it is good to know (for all working on Windows ;-)